# Max queries per hour limit is 36 000. I have 100 queries per pageview. 360 pages viewed per hour and I'm bust?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, web-hosting

**My problem is that:**

1) I make approx 100 queries to the MYSQL database on every pageview; the number is given to me by the Query Monitor plugin for Wordpress.

2) My hosting company operates with the following limit: max_queries_per_hour = 36 000.

Does this really mean that if 360 pageviews are happening within the same hour, the total queries to the database in that hour reaches the 36 000 limit from my host and my website is unavailable potentially for the next hour, till the limit resets?

If this is so, then either my queries for my pages is *insanely high*, or my hosting companys limits are *very low*?

I know caching could be a good thing here, but really wonder if my theory/explanation above is correct. Is that the way it works?

PS: Most of the database queries are SELECT, only a few UPDATE and INSERTs.

Comment: I would say "my queries for my pages is insanely high" AND "my hosting companys limits are very low`". A bad combo, are you using a free service for hosting?

Comment: 100 queries per page isn't really that high for wordpress. The hosting limits are very low.

Comment: @user3783243 Nope, using a very reliable and well-known company here in Norway. Its about 100$ a year for hosting, email, SSL etc.

Comment: @KGreene Yes, that is what I've found through research also. Weird.

Comment: Using a backend cache like redis and a frontend cache like wp_supercache will greatly increase the pageloads you can do - like you said.

Comment: Reading about Redis just now, @KGreene! Cheers!

Comment: 36,000 queries seems really arbitrary.  Shouldn't queried fields with indexes be cheaper?  You can bring down an entire mysql instance with one query on a non-indexed field, whereas a proper select would be done in 0.02 seconds.  Etc., etc..  I would look for another hosting company.

Comment: 100 queries per view might not be high for wordpress but it's still insanely high in the relative scope of all things. wordpress sounds badly designed.

Comment: @parttimeturtle yes and yes.  Like mosts things in PHP, Wordpress is poorly designed

Answer (score 0):

To finish this off:

I will manage my queries with transients in Wordpress; this will help me reduce the database queries that are the problem.